# Cocoa: Sandbox entitlement to launch another application

Tags: cocoa, sandbox, nsworkspace

I'm calling

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:path];
```

From my sandboxed app, and I'm getting this error in the console:

> 9/5/11 12:23:12.462 PM lsboxd: refusing to spawn < PATH REDACTED > for 21383 - reason -10826
>
> 9/5/11 12:23:12.463 PM App: spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=54 label=[0x0-0x1994993].MYApp path=< PATH REDACTED > flags=0
>
> 9/5/11 12:23:12.464 PM App: LSOpenFromURLSpec() returned -10810 for application < PATH REDACTED > (null).

In other words, I'm clearly getting blocked by the "Launch Services Sandbox Daemon" (lsboxd) which doesn't think app 1 should be launching app 2.

For the record 10826 is "The user does not have permission to launch the application" and then 10810 is "An unknown error has occurred"

Does anyone know of an entitlement for this case?

How can you launch other apps from a sandboxed app (please don't say AppleScript - it's a non-functioning nightmare, especially when called from sandboxed apps or XPC services).  The ideal is a way to use the (severely crippled) NSWorkspace from within a sandbox.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter of `launchApplication:` is the application's *name* (i.e. something like `@"Safari"`), not its path. That way, it's been working without any special entitlements for me. I don't think you can launch apps at arbitrary paths from a sandboxed app without using PowerBox.

Comment: The path/name is optional; it works either way.  The main issue is the sandbox preventing the launch, and the lack of an entitlement around this.  From what I gather on the forums there in fact is no entitlement.  This is the main question, unless there is another solution.

Comment: You seem to be right about the path/name, didn't know that. I just tried launching an app this way in a sandboxed app and it seems to work fine as long as the app is in /Applications (I would assume that ~/Application also works but haven't tried this).