# NSWorkspace launchApplication:showIcon:autolaunch: - how to check autolaunch flag?

Tags: cocoa, autologin, nsapplication, nsworkspace

I have implemented a login item as I was recommended in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536477/mac-os-x-start-on-launch-while-in-app-store). In the helper app I launch the main app using `NSWorkspace` method `launchApplication:showIcon:autolaunch:`, sending `YES` to autolaunch parameter.

The problem is in following: I need to check if the applications was autolaunched not to show start tooltip. The only variant I found is `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"autolaunch"]`, and it returns `NO` always.

The problem could be solved using launch arguments - but sandbox, unfortunately, cuts them too.

Is there something I missed?

Comment: fixed. Didn't notice the button earlier, thanx for help)

Comment: I don't think I get your question - can you rephrase what you're trying to check for the launched app?

Comment: I need to check if it was autolaunched (after system startup) or not. When I start my main app with helper I send Boolean parameter to NSWorkspace - and I need to retrieve it in the main application.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to hide the launched application:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplicationAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:appPath] options:NSWorkspaceLaunchAndHide configuration:nil error:nil];
```

If you want to set additional parameters, you can give the method a custom configuration dictionary.
If you have the launcher inside the application bundle:

```
NSString *appPath=[[[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MacOS/myApp"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out if it will work for me from within the sandbox.