# Using SMLoginItemSetEnabled, App does not show under "Login Items"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am using [`SMLoginItemSetEnabled`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436318/how-to-create-a-helper-application-for-mac-app-to-start-it-on-user-login/8144632#8144632) to launch an app on login. Everything works fine, except that the App does not show under "Login Items" in the "User Preferences" window. I have tried this in OS X Lion.

1. Is this the expected behavior?
2. Is there a way to manually stop the App from launching on login? I can't find anything in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` or `/Library/LaunchAgents`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is expected behavior.
[Apple Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-BAJJBJEG) says:

> Login items installed using the Service Management framework are not visible in System Preferences and can only be removed by the application that installed them.

---

Yes, just change Disabled to true for your bundle identifier in launchd's overrides.plist.
I wrote you a command to do just this:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :com.yourcompany.helper-CFBundleIdentifier-here:Disabled true' /var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.$UID/overrides.plist
```

- Note: Replace com.yourcompany.helper-CFBundleIdentifier-here with your BundleIdentifier.

Comment: heads up: looks like 10.10 now uses `/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/disabled.$UID.plist` to keep track of enabled/disabled state.